# A problem with the proof of the equality.

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I have two confluent hypergeometric functions 
$$A=M(\alpha, 1; e^{i\omega{t}})$$
and
$$B=M(\beta, 1; e^{i\omega{t}})$$
Where
$$M(a, b, z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_{k}}{(b)_{k}k!}z^{k}$$
It seems obvious to me that
$$\bar{A}B=A\bar{B}$$
Can someone help me prove this using cauchy formula or something?

Comment: If I was doing it, I would take A, B apart into sine/cos odd/even parts term by term using Euler's expansion  on  individual terms.  Then play with the results in real terms.  An alternative might be to take derivatives and use Cauchy derivative criteria for analytic functions.  Bear in mind that I am not sure your hypothesis is true.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Let $\alpha = 0$
Then $M(0,1,x)=A=\bar{A}=1 $
but then if $\beta =1 $
Then $M(1,1,e^{i\omega t})=B \neq \bar{B} $